# TFS messing with my workflow coding style.

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, version-control, tfs

I recently converted from Vault to TFS for C# coding (language probably doesn't matter) in VS2010.  My workflow used to be as follows:

If I don't want to check a file out or the file is already checked out by someone else, I simply remove the read-only attribute and start editing.  At that point, Vault would stay out of my way.  Later on, I would just merge my changes.

With TFS, by default, it wouldn't let me edit the file at all (because it checked out by someone else), even though I removed its read-only attribute.  So I went into Tools/Options/Source Control/Environment and checked the `Allow checked-in items to be edited`.

This setting does allow me to edit the file, however, every time I press Ctrl-S to save it, it complains that the file is locked for check-out.

How can I get TFS to edit my files in peace?

Comment: IIRC the is some 'check out file automatically'. It is a PITA though if you are offline...

Answer (score 4):

You should have no issues unless the other person who is working on the file is `locking` it when they check it out.

My settings are as follows and work well for your situation:

```
Options -> Source Control -> Environment

Team Foundation
[] Get everything when a solution or project is opened
[] Check in everything when closing a solution or project
[] Display silent checkout command in menus
[] Keep items checked out when checking in

Checked-in items
  Saving: Check out automatically
  Editing: Check out automatically
  [] Allow checked-in items to be edited
```

In the "Team Explorer" window right-click on your `{Team Project}` -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control

Make sure that "Check-out Settings" has `[x] Enable multiple check-out`

Also when checking out files make sure "unchanged" is selected such as in this screen shot:

[image: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=C0257D84E94B7A32&id=C0257D84E94B7A32!370]

from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsversioncontrol/thread/4353d676-1794-4db0-9d9d-f2a231315980

Comment: How do you not check out file for "locking"?  The other person simply right-clicked on a file and selected Check Out.

Comment: So your settings are basically the defaults?

Comment: When you go to check out a file manually you will have an option for a lock type.  The default is 'unchanged' in which no additional locks are placed, but there is an option to place a lock preventing others from checking it out.  Most people tend to just use the settings above so that editing a file automatically checks it out (without adding a lock on it).

Comment: @AngryHacker: it sounds like either someone has changed the lock setting on the Team Project, or you're using the CMMI process template (which ships with this setting on by default).  To enable multiple checkout (ie, stop automatically upgrading edit pending changes into check-out locks) right click on your Team Project in Team Explorer and select Team Project Settings -> Source Control...  In the Check-out Settings tab, make sure "Enable multiple check-out" is checked.  If this setting is already set, well, you'll need to sort this out with your lock-happy coworker.

Comment: @Servy I see - the `lock type` dropdown is grayed out on my box.  Probably it was locked down by an admin.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yes, it was set by an admin, it looks like, and I have no power to change it.

Comment: Sorry, got distracted with work so wasn't able to put the other settings in my post, but yeah those are the others to look at. You'll probably want to talk to the TFS Admin if you can and see if they have a good reason to always lock files on checkout. VS / TFS has a good "compare" utility built in to help merge files that multiple people have edited.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with multiple people checking out the same file at the same time.  That is a large part of why source control was created in the first place, so that this could be done.  By checking out the file, and not just editing it locally outside of TFS's knowledge, you are also telling others that you are working on the file (useful information to have).

As stated earlier, unless the file(s) are checked out and locked nobody will be prevented from accessing or modifying the file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a setting available for each project that will explicitly disable multiple check-outs if it is not selected.

If you have appropriate permission, in the Team Explorer... right-click on your project and choose "Team Project Settings -> Source Control...".  On the "Check-out Settings" tab, there is a checkbox for "Enable multiple check-out".  Verify that the option is checked.

Answer (score 2):

If you're used to git (or are willing to give it a try) then I highly recommend git tfs. It gets rid of the whole annoying paradigm of having to clear readonly flags on files, as every file is effectively cloned from the TFS source tree into a git repository. Then when you push your changes back into TFS it marshals the changes back into a format TFS approves of.

For example

```
git tfs quick-clone http:tfs-server/tfs/yourCollection $/YourCode/YourBranch YourDirectory
```

checks out all your files from TFS into `YourDirectory`, you can then modify these files as you would any other files on your computer, then to send them back to tfs you can issue the commands

```
git commit -a
```

To check the files into git, then

```
git tfs ct
```

To push the files into the TFS repository. More details can be found here: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs